# How can I make this URL validation regular expression less greedy?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

So I have the following regular expression:

```
https?://(www\.)?flickr\.com/photos/(.+)/?
```

To match against the following URL:

```
http://www.flickr.com/photos/username/
```

How can I stop the final forward slash (`/`) from being included in the username sub-pattern `(.+)`?

I have tried:

```
https?://(www\.)?flickr\.com/photos/(.+?)/?
```

But then it only matches the first letter of the username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
https?://(?:www\.)?flickr\.com/photos/([^/]+)/?
```

I added `?:` to the first group so it's not capturing, then used `[^/]` instead of the dot in the last match. This assures you that everything between "photos/" and the very next "/" is captured.

If you need to capture the first `www` just use this:

```
https?://(www\.)?flickr\.com/photos/([^/]+)/?
```

Comment: Nice tip with `?:` I did not know about the non capturing modifier!

Comment: I edited adding some "\" because you have to notice that "flickr\.com" matches "flickr.com", but "flickr.com" matches also "flickrWcom". So mind the dots ;)

Comment: I noticed some of the escaping had gone AWOL :). My final `preg_match` ready regex looks like this `#https?://(?:www\.)?flickr\.com/photos/([^/]+)/?#`. Note I have changed the delimiting character from `/` to `#` to avoid having to escape all the `/` in the URL.

Comment: If you need everything up to, but not including, a possible final slash, possibly including slashes, try something like `(.*[^/])/?$`

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure it doesn't match the forward slash:

```
https?://(?:www\.)?flickr\.com/photos/([^/]+)/?
```

You could also make the regex lazy (which is what I guess you were doing with the `(.+?)` syntax), but the above will work just fine

Answer (score 1):

Change `(.+)` to `([^/]+)`. This will match until it encounters a `/`, so you might want to throw some other stuff in the class too.

Answer (score 1):

There are generally two ways to do this:

Append a question mark, to make the matching non-greedy. `.*` will match as much as possible, `.*?` will match as little as possible.

Exclude the character you want to match next. If you want to stop on `/`, use `[^/]*`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know there will be a trailing slash, take out the final `?`.

Comment: There may or may not be a final slash.